# How do I make an alert show how long it took to complete a certain amount of questions in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, timer, uialertview, nstimer

I want to show the user how long it took him or her to answer a certain amount of questions (for example 5) as an alert.  I believe that I have the correct timer in place although I could be wrong.  How would I finish the coding?

```
- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
static int count = 0;
count += 1;
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc]
               initWithFormat:@"%d", count];
self.timer.text = s;
[s release];
}

- (void)generate
{
int a = 1 + arc4random() % 12;
int b = 1 + arc4random() % 12;

int sum = a * b;

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d * %d = ", a, b];

label.tag = sum;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
[super viewDidLoad];

[self generate];

[self.answer becomeFirstResponder];

UIAlertView *alert;
{alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
          initWithTitle:@"Welcome to iCanMultiply!" 
          message:@"Tap 'Start' to start the game" 
          delegate: self
          cancelButtonTitle:@"Start" 
          otherButtonTitles: nil];
}

[alert show];
[alert release];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateCounter:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
}
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {
int num = [answer.text intValue];

UIAlertView *alert;
if (num == label.tag)

{ 
    // answer was correct
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
             initWithTitle:@"Correct"
             message:@"Bet you can't do that twice!"
             delegate:self
             cancelButtonTitle:@"Next Question"
             otherButtonTitles: nil];

    // use the alert tag to mark that answer was correct
    alert.tag = 1;
} else 
{
    // answer is incorrect
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
             initWithTitle:@"Wrong!" 
             message:@"Sorry, try again..."
             delegate:self 
             cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again" 
             otherButtonTitles: nil];
}

// show and release the alert
[alert show];
[alert release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 1)
{
    [self generate];

    answer.text = @"";
}
}
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way than incrementing a counter every second.  Considering that it will take on the order of a few seconds for each question, you'll end up with a sizable error.

Answer (score 0):

Store that value and then display it in an alert view.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message@"It took you %@ seconds.",time delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Let me know if the ,time works. I haven't tested this yet, but it should work.